# Can I upgrade MacBookPro13"(Early 2011-1333 MHZ DDR3-2.3 GHZ i5) to 16GB 1600 MHZ RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro

Can I install 16 GB 1600 MHZ RAM on my MacBookPro 13" (Early 2011-4GB 1333 MHZ DDR3 ) with 2.3 GHZ i5 processor? According to Apple support, I can upgrade upto 8 GB only and does not provide information about 1600 MHZ RAM. Please help.

Comment: That system takes 2 - 204-pin PC-10600 (1333 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM which Apple states 8 GB max but has been proven by authoritative sources to take 16 GB of the specified type, not 1600 MHz though.

Answer (score 1):

The source I have, MacTracker, says your laptop can be upgraded to 16 GB. I don't know about the 1600 MHz but I assume that would be ok if all of the memory modules were 1600 MHz.